# Are lumens required for a custom network?

Tags: stellar-core, horizon, stellar-sdk, lumens, private-network

New to Stellar so forgive me if this is not the smartest question, but are real lumens still required on a custom network? I would like to use the stellar blockchain for "transaction" validations but not for real currency exchanges.  Only data points. Given the lumen reserves required for trust-lines and transactions, I am looking for a solution that would keep the need for real lumens to a minimum or remove the need for them totally.

Basically I want to do the following:
Record "transactions" between two wallets.  Will supply some data points (say a number, two ids and a time of the transaction).  There would be multiple wallets so not the same two wallets every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A custom network is basically just running an own seperate ledger/blockchain, so it does not cost any real XLM. There will be your own equivalent of network tokens that you'll be able to mint yourself since it will be your network.

However there ain't no such thing as a free lunch. You'll have to run at least three full validator nodes, a horizon server, backups and this kind of stuff.

Comment: Thank you sui!  So even when using the Stellar-SDK you connected to a standalone Stellar Core and Horizion nodes you are "free" of trust line and transaction base reserves? e.g. 0.5XLM per transaction, etc

And of course.  Services cost for a reason!  Time saved from devOps and physical operations of nodes is the most valuable asset  I am a proponent of using the public net for exactly these reason, but need to collect all the info to present to the team to persuade them. ;)

Comment: Yeah, you could use your networks native token as you would use XLM on the stellar main net and I guess you could configure pretty much anything to your needs.

Comment: Another contra argument for an own network is "the five pillars of cryptocurrency" (from Andreas Antonopoulos), a blockchain is pretty much pointless if it is not: open, public, borderless, neutral, and censorship resistant. Private blockchains barely can satisfy these requirements.

Comment: 100% sui. Without public consensus, it’s just a audited ledger database.